# MS Access 2007 Performance Issues

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am building a database is Access 2007, and we don't even have any data yet but the database is constantly freezing. I used the built in performance checker, and it said everything was fine, but I am worried that the database will be unusably slow if I don't fix it soon.

Here is why I think it may be slow.

1. We have 300+ queries saved in the
   database, all of which need to run
   weekly.
2. We have 4 main reports and a sub
   report for nearly all of the queries
   above. Why? Because the 4 main
   reports need information from all of
   the queries, and we are using sub
   reports as the source.
3. A few of our queries are pulling
   information from at least 15 other
   sub queries.

Other than this, I don't know why it could be slow, unless it's just my computer. Could someone pleas give me some insight about what might be wrong, how I might improve our database's performance, and if this amount of queries and sub reports is abnormally high.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the database on a network share? And/or is it accessing tables elsewhere on the network?

Comment: Yes to both, is that the problem?

Comment: It may be, it may not - either way it's another variable that needs to be considered. It may appear to be freezing because it is waiting on a network resource, and/or because network traffic is causing lag.

Comment: What do you mean "constantly freezing"? Does Task Manager show activity for MS Access? Is some other process grabbing the CPU, perhaps? Do you have anti-virus software running? If so, turn off scanning of any Access files, as it's entirely a waste of CPU cycles to do so.

Comment: Do any error messages accompany the "freezing", and by freezing to you mean the hourglass never goes away, perhaps, or that progress bar gets to 99% fairly quickly b ut then stays there for 10-20 minutes?

Comment: No errors accompany the freezing. Usually what happens is I'll open a query or report, or just run a query, and the entire application stops responding. I have to kill it from Task manager because the hourglass (well, it's more like a circle) just stays on the screen. Anyways, I'm glad no one seems to think my queries are the problem, that would be a pain to have to redo. Thanks for your answers though, I'll try to check on the antivirus software and the network traffic to see if they could be the cause.

Comment: In Windows 7 the "hourglass" cursor is a circle with a blue highlight going round and round. If that's still going, it means the process is still executing (as far as Windows is concerned). You can check by looking in Task Manager to see if MSACCESS.EXE is actually doing something. You need to do this before you do anything else -- I'm not convinced that the app has locked up at all. It seems to me just as likely that you're just impatient with an operation that is slow. Whether or not it can be speeded up is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links to tables on network share, or even a default printer that is part of the network can cause many delays. One often used solution is to keep open (force) a persistent connection. During development you can simply in the front end open any linked table (one that is linked to the back end), and then minimize it. This often will solve those delays. The list of other things to check can be found here:

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm

If the above persistent connection works, you also want to ensure in your startup code you open a connection to the back end to a global database var, or perhaps open up a table to a global reocrdset.